# C++ How to dynamically select a file handle according to the type of data that should be written?

Tags: c++, io

I've got a `class outputInterface;` that should handle the output (to files) of some data. The data is contained in objects of some custom classes, say `dataClassA` and `dataClassB`, that all derive from a common base class `dataClassBase`.

Now I want the data to be written to different files according to its type. So data of type `dataClassA` should go to `fileA`, data of type `dataClassB` should go to `fileB` and so on. As this output happens very often I would like the file handles (`fileA` and `fileB`) to stay open, i.e. I don't want to open and close the files for the output of each piece of data. One `outputInterface` object can be expected to exist all the time.

So what I would like to achieve is something like this:

- Dynamically associate data of type `dataClassA` with the file handle `fileA` etc.
- When receiving data of type `dataClassA` check whether `fileA` is already connected to a file, if not, open the file.

How can I get this behavior (or least something similar / better)?
I've been thinking of making the file handles static members of `dataClassA` and `dataClassB` (or the base class `dataClassBase`?). But then, how do I take care of closing the files? I would have to somehow keep track of the data types that have actually been used (the files that have actually been opened).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#ifndef OUTPUTINTERFACE?H   
#define OUTPUTINTERFACE?H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

class DataClass
{
public:
    virtual bool WriteData(std::ofstream& FStream) = 0;
};
class DataClass1 :
    public DataClass
{    
    virtual bool WriteData(std::ofstream& FStream)
    {
        FStream << "teletubbies";
    }
};    
class DataClass2 :
    public DataClass
{
    virtual bool WriteData(std::ofstream& FStream)
    {
        FStream << "garbage";
    }
};


class OutputInterface
{
public:
    OutputInterface()
    {
    }
    ~OutputInterface()
    {
        //Release stream pointers
    }
    template<typename T>
    bool WriteData(T& Data)
    {
        std::string dClassUID = std::string(typeid(T).name);
        tFStreamMap::iterator it this->streamMap.find(dClassUID);
        std::ofstream* stream = NULL;

        if(it != streamMap.end())
        {
            stream = it->second;
        }
        else
        {
            stream = new std::ofstream();
            stream->open(dClassUID + ".txt");
            streamMap.insert(std::make_pair(dClassUID, stream));
        }

        Data.WriteData(stream);
    }
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::ofstream*> tFStreamMap;
    tFStreamMap streamMap;
};    

#endif
```

This is just a prove of concept and can be optimized in many ways.
I would rather stick with overloaded functions than with runtime type checks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The downside of this approach would be a very limited flexibility. I would have to explicitly include an ofstream object and overloaded functions for each of my data objects (that would be about 10). This seems somehow awkward.. And might yield problems when adding a new data type but omitting to adapt the OutputInterface. But maybe it would really be the most simple approach.

Comment: The updated concept looks very promising, I'm currently testing it. The part with the map-container based on the typeid gives me the flexibility I needed. I'm combining it with the idea of #James Kanze (using type_index or a custom implementation thereof) and I'll try to implement WriteData with a pointer to the base class instead of using a template.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to implement in C++11, using an
`std::map<std::type_index, std::ostring*> outputMap`.  (In C++03, you'll have to
implement the equivalent of `std::type_index` yourself.)  You get the
output stream using `outputMap[typeid(*data)]`.  The only problem is
getting the streams into the map to begin with: you can do something
like:

```
std::ostream*& destPtr = outputMap[typeid(*data)];
if ( destPtr == NULL ) {
    destPtr = new std::ofstream("...");
}
std::ostream& dest = *destPtr;
```

But from where do you get the filename?

There's also the question of when you close the streams: you can't
normally close an output stream in a destructor, since closing an output
stream is an operation which can fail, and you need to detect and react
to that failure.  Probably with an exception, which is why you don't
want to do it in a destructor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possibility to use a map with keys based on the type_info. C++11 is not yet an option (using gcc 4.4 mostly) but I extracted the relevant parts from the proposed gcc 4.6 implementations of type_index. I'll combine it with the framework proposed by #Mythli.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "data" part comes from `dataClassBase`, you can make a virtual/pure-virtual function 'WriteData` in this class, and let derive class implement it.

The class `outputInterface` may take objects of type `dataClassBase` and would directly call `WriteData`. Other than `WriteData` you may also add other virtual functions in `dataClassBase`

You did not mention relationship between `outputInterface` and `dataClassBase`

Comment: Yes, but this wouldn't solve the problem with the persistently open file handle, would it? If I put the output routines into the data classes as you suggest, I would open and close the output file every time. And this is something, I'd like to avoid.
PS: Currently there is not relationship between `outputInterface` and `dataClassBase`.

Comment: Your question is too wide, you didn't state what your actual problem was. Keep them open or open-close the files - that's all your design decision, and depends on the frequency of such "calls". How many of such objects (dataClassBase) would be stored?

Comment: Well, my decision would be that I want to keep the files open as the output operations are very frequent. Currently about 10 different data types would need to be handled, this could of course be done by explicitly discriminating between different types in my interface, but I am looking for the flexibility to vary the number of data types, add new ones etc.